# CIQRCodeGenerator Providing Inconsistent Results

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, core-image

I am experiencing a problem using `CIQRCodeGenerator` to create a QR code: when I generate the code at first, it is crisp, but when I run the function again, with the same input, the QR code becomes blurry:

Initial Run (more clear):

[image: initial function run]

Second Run (more blurry):

[image: second function run]

The following function is first called in `viewWillAppear` and subsequently triggered after the user taps a button.

```
func generateQRCodeFromString(string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSISOLatin1StringEncoding)

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        filter.setValue("H", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")
        let transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(10, 10)

        if let output = filter.outputImage?.imageByApplyingTransform(transform) {
            return UIImage(CIImage: output)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

A sample project illustrating the problem is available here: http://jakeserver.com/Uploads/Apps/QR_Test.zip

Is there a reason why the UIImage becomes blurry after the function is run a second time with the same input?

**EDIT - Added More Information**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    qrCode.image = generateQRCodeFromString("test", size: qrCode.frame.size);
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    qrCodeWidth.constant = self.view.frame.width * 0.8;
}
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    qrCode.image = generateQRCodeFromString("test", size: qrCode.frame.size);
}
```

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` `qrCode.frame.size` is probably the incorrect size. Maybe move that to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? Also, I think you should be calling `super` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: @AaronBrager Thank you for all of your help. I think moving the call into the didLayout method fixed it in this instance. I had one more quick question: would it be possible to make it any sharper than it currently is? Even with a scale of 2, it still appears a little blurry.

Comment: @AaronBrager I figured out the answer to my followup question, I had to double the width and height values in the scale line. Thank you again for all of your help.

Comment: BTW, you don't need `qrCodeWidth.constant = self.view.frame.width * 0.8` — you can just create an "equal widths" constraint with a multiplier

Comment: @AaronBrager is that more memory/processor efficient?

Comment: I doubt it makes a difference in terms of efficiency but it might make your code shorter and therefore easier to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the blurriness changes between runs (maybe an internal implementation detail), but in Objective-C code I worked around this by making the QR code and then manually writing the image into a larger sized bitmap context.

I took a stab at porting that code to Swift and came up with this:

```
func generateQRCodeFromString(string: String, size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    guard let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSISOLatin1StringEncoding),
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") else { return nil }

    filter.setDefaults()
    filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
    filter.setValue("H", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")

    guard let image = filter.outputImage else { return nil }

    let extent = CGRectIntegral(image.extent)
    let scale = min(size.width / extent.width, size.height / extent.height);

    let (height, width) = (extent.height * scale, extent.width * scale)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.None.rawValue)

    guard let bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(width), Int(height), 8, 0, colorSpace, bitmapInfo.rawValue) else { return nil }

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmapContext, CGInterpolationQuality.None)
    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmapContext, CGFloat(scale), CGFloat(scale))
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmapContext, extent, CIContext().createCGImage(image, fromRect: extent))

    if let scaledImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext) {
        return UIImage(CGImage: scaledImage)
//        You might need to use this instead:
//        return UIImage(CGImage: <#T##CGImage#>, scale: <#T##CGFloat#>, orientation: <#T##UIImageOrientation#>)

    }

    return nil
}
```

Will that work for your use case?

BTW, I don't think this caused your issue, but you weren't unwrapping `data` (`dataUsingEncoding(_:)` returns `NSData?` not `NSData`).

Comment: I'm also not sure if `CGImageAlphaInfo.None`, `CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst`, or `CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipLast` would be most appropriate here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now, it appears as though the opposite issue occurs: the image starts off blurry, then becomes crisper when the button is tapped. Any ideas why this may be occurring?

Comment: @JakeChasan None off the top of my head. Might be related to your view / view controller setup and not your `CIFilter` implementation? Can you post your `viewWillAppear` and button tap code?

Comment: I have added the viewDidLoad, viewWillLayoutSubviews, and the button tapped method.

Answer (score 1):

Updated version of Aaron's great answer, for Swift 5+

```
func generateQRCodeFromString(string: String, size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    guard let data = string.data(using: .isoLatin1),
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") else { return nil }

    filter.setDefaults()
    filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
    filter.setValue("H", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")

    guard let image = filter.outputImage else { return nil }

    let extent = CGRectIntegral(image.extent)
    let scale = min(size.width / extent.width, size.height / extent.height);

    let (height, width) = (extent.height * scale, extent.width * scale)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue)

    guard let bitmapContext = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue) else { return nil }

    bitmapContext.interpolationQuality = CGInterpolationQuality.none
    bitmapContext.scaleBy(x: CGFloat(scale), y: CGFloat(scale))
    
    bitmapContext.draw(CIContext().createCGImage(image, from: extent)!, in: extent)

    if let scaledImage = bitmapContext.makeImage() {
        return UIImage(cgImage: scaledImage)

    }

    return nil
}
```